# What can be causing disk activity in empty external drives as soon as I mount them

Tags: xubuntu, hard-drive, backup

I have some 4TB drives that never saw heavy use, and have been given new partition tables and one large ext4 partition each for storing backups.  Some of them exhibit the odd behavior that as soon as they are mounted, the drive dock activity light starts flashing and never seems to stop.  The rate varies a bit between the drives.  Not all drives do this at all.  The flashing stops as soon as I umount them.  None of these drives has been used yet since repartitioning except create a backup.log text file and a single line indicating when it was started.

fsck comes up clean.

Should I be worried?  If so, what should I be worried about?  All this on Xubuntu 18.04.4.

Comment: Install `iotop` to see what's running the disks.

Comment: Probably the lazy journal init that ext4 does after formatting, but yea try iotop.